# PhpMyAdmin SQL Query Code Reverting Back To Old Code

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to change the SQL query under the SQL tab in PhpMyAdmin but the old code keeps coming back every time I navigate off that page (and thus, giving me an error message again). How can I stop it from reverting back to it's old erroneous code? I have the new code at the ready. Is there some sort of setting I need to tweak?

Actually, I don't really need any code here at all, unless it's required. I'm new to PhpMyAdmin and just want to set it up so that I can follow along with a video tutorial.

When I try to click on the **Databases** tab
[image: When I try to click on the **Databases** tab]

The old code in the **SQL** tab. Keeps coming back...
[image]

Note: The code was changed to that shown below that works. But it "reverts" back somehow. Good code:

[image]

Comment: You need to work on your image quality (like my edits) to make stuff not so much of a hassle to read it.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a version incompatibility. Your screenshot shows you using MySQL version 5.7 with phpMyAdmin 4.2; this is not supported and guaranteed to not work properly. For use with MySQL 5.7, you should use the latest phpMyAdmin (which is currently the 4.6 branch; 4.6.4 was released on 2016-08-16).

For more information about version compatibility, see the "Requirements" section of the documentation included with each download, or the information listed with each version at https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/

Comment: I tried updating my phpmyadmin version on the Google Compute instance my apache server is running on but it didn't take. I used `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin` and `sudo apt-get update` but nothing.

Comment: Have you used apt to install the whole stack (Apache/nginx, PHP, MySQL, and phpMyAdmin)? Which release are you tracking in sources.list?

Comment: I'm pretty new to this so I'm not very clear on the sources.list part, but I installed Apache, PHP5, and PHPMyAdmin individually. I also installed the MySQLserver, and it looks like the client version came with it. I also did a `sudo apt-get install php5-mysql` (based on a similar StackOverflow question). Are you sure that this is what's causing that old code to come back? Others say that this shouldn't really matter.

Comment: Debian and Ubuntu use the apt package manager to install packages and handle dependencies. Normally, you use the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file to tell Apt which version you want to follow (stable, unstable, jessie, etc). The package managers usually take great steps to ensure that software is compatible within a release version, but sometimes people want new features so they add an entry to `sources.list` for newer software, which isn't always compatible. The only Debian version that carries phpMyAdmin 4.2 is "jessie"/stable, but it packages MYSQL 5.5, not 5.7 which is what you have.

Comment: That's what makes me think there's something strange going on in your apt sources. Anyway, I don't have a clear source that shows which versions are supported by phpMyAdmin 4.2, so I could be wrong, but that's definitely the first thing that came to mind. phpMyAdmin 4.4 is only good for up to MySQL 5.5 (see https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/), so my assumption is that an earlier version is also not compatible with 5.7, but I admit I could be wrong. The big mystery to me here is why your apt is providing MySQL 5.7 with phpMyAdmin 4.2.

Comment: Would it be better to install a full stack instead? Are they normally preconfigured to be ready to use?

Comment: A prebuilt package such as XAMPP is generally an "all-in-one" solution where it handles all the dependencies and making sure you get everything together. Then again, that's kind of the point of apt, too, which didn't work out too well for you. You might have good luck with using XAMPP (or something similar); you'll probably want to back up then remove any PHP, Apache, or MySQL first, though so they don't conflict.